# Type Research: »Die Rettung des Abendlandes« by Ernst Otto Montanus

Tags: font-identification, typefaces, history, research

Recently, I came across this book cover in an old antiquarian shop and I was immediately struck by the typeface used. All attempts at researching the typeface's name or origin or maybe the designer have lead nowhere so far. Variations in the individual letter shapes hint at it actually being a custom lettering created specifically for the cover (for example in the the »n«).

Anyone who can help me with my investigation?

[image: Book Cover]

Comment: Have you tried any automated font-id sites, as per our [font-id requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366)? Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent I did so extensively, without results unfortunately. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: I agree that the lettering is not type but artwork. Possibly done with an Osmiroid, Graphos, or SpeedBall pens. All the counters are different sizes and the set is different for all the same letters.  I find the blackened-out portion intriguing. I can make out a segmented six-pointed star with a swastika centred. That may help date the work.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an attempt to stylise Latin characters as though they were runes - like a kind of faux-runic typeface.  That's all I can think of, if it's any help. Perhaps you could google that?

Also, it's worth noting that there are substantial differences between letter forms that should be the same, which suggests that this is not a typeface at all, but hand lettering.